# show that $19-5\sqrt[3]{2}-8\sqrt[3]{4}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-number-theory

I found by numerical experiment the [norm](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf) of $19-5\sqrt[3]{2}-8\sqrt[3]{4}$ (result of multiplying conjugates) is: $$0.9999999999989706-4.4408920985006262 \times 10^{-16}i$$ but I am betting this is just $1$.  How can I show this is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$?  Here is another possible unit:
$$ 521-62\sqrt[3]{2}-279\sqrt[3]{4} $$

Comment: This is the difference between numerical and symbolic computation. Try it in Wolfram Alpha: the "preview" will show you something like 0.999999999, but when you hit Enter, you should get 1.

Comment: 1) Show that $\alpha=\root3\of2-1$ is a unit. 2) Calculate $\alpha^5$. For the second part 3) square the result of the first part.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I should have read through the comments before submitting an answer identical to the above.

Comment: @Lubin: I have this habit of occasionally posting comments like this, trying to leave work for the original asker. It might make things simpler, to myself and fellow users, to post them as answers. But, old habits die hard. No fault on your part, the comments have much lower visibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, 
Given integers $a,b,c,$ and cubic form
$$ f(a,b,c) = a^3+2 b^3-6 a b c+4 c^3 = \left|\begin{bmatrix} a & 2c & 2b\\b & a & 2c\\ c & b & a\end{bmatrix}\right|,  $$

That is because $f(a,b,c) = \det(aI + b X + c X^2),$ where
$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2\\1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.  $$ Then $X^3 = 2 I$ and $X^4 = 2 X.$

The elements with norm $1$ and coefficients below $600$ in absolute value are

```
      -161     -99     180
       -35      24       3
        -7      -2       6
        -1       1       0
         1      -2       1
         1       0       0
         1       1       1
         1       3      -3
         1     100     -80
         5       4       3
        19      -5      -8
        19      15      12
        41     -59      21
        73      58      46
       281     223     177
       521     -62    -279
```

You want $a = 19, b = -5, c = -8.$ The resulting determinant is $1,$ both times.

```
? f = 19 * id - 5 * x - 8 * x2
%5 = 
[19 -16 -10]

[-5 19 -16]

[-8 -5 19]

? matdet(f)
%6 = 1
? x
%7 = 
[0 0 2]

[1 0 0]

[0 1 0]

? x^2
%9 = 
[0 2 0]

[0 0 2]

[1 0 0]

? f = 521 * id - 62 * x - 279 * x2
%10 = 
[521 -558 -124]

[-62 521 -558]

[-279 -62 521]

? matdet(f)
%11 = 1
?
```

Answer (score 9):

Multiply your number by $$281+223\sqrt[3]{2}+177\sqrt[3]{4}$$
and the result is $1$.

How did I find this?  I multiplied by $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$, set the result to $1$, and solved the $3\times 3$ linear system.

Comment: +1 for this answer. This is the beauty of linear algebra. Despites its name it solves problem in higher degree algebra!

Answer (score 2):

You can go back to the first principle. Use the fact that the $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha]$  generated by powers of $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$
is in fact a subfield of the complex (or real) numbers.

Calculate the inverse of $19-5\sqrt[3]{2}-8\sqrt[3]{4}$ by Eulidean algorithm in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ for gcd between $19-5x-8x^2$ and $x^3-2$. If the inverse   has integer coefficients we are done.

PS: Computational experiments can be made exact with packages like SAGE (www.sagemath.org). So you need not have to deal with decimals.

Comment: I would like to be able to upvote this answer more than once!

Comment: Thanks tracing. But this is not any clever idea. It is just canonical.  We show $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha]$ is a field for a given algebraic number $\alpha$ by showing $\mathbf{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ is a field for the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ by using Euclidean algorithm.  Here one needs to verify the extra condition that it is an algebraic integer.