# Alternative definition of algebraic integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Why can an algebraic integer (in $\mathbb{C}$ integer over $\mathbb{Z}$) be defined as an eigenvalue of some matrix with integer coefficients?

Comment: What do you mean by eigenvalue of some polynomial?

Comment: what is an eigenvalue of a polynomial?

Comment: Forgive me for such mistake :P I was absentminded while writing, edited anyways..

Comment: For this standard result see e.g. S. Fallat, [Algebraic integers and tensor products of matrices,](https://cms.math.ca/crux/v22/n8/page341-343.pdf) or Robin Chapman's [Notes on algebraic integers](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/notes/algn.pdf) or many other expositions that can be found with obvious web searches.

Comment: actually, the integer is best thought of as the companion matrix itself. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883573/finding-units-of-mathbbz-sqrt33/1883652#1883652  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1881822/show-that-19-5-sqrt32-8-sqrt34-is-a-unit-in-mathbbz-sqrt32/1881834#1881834

Comment: See also [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/713394/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algebraic integer is generally defined as a root of a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $A$ is a matrix with integer entries, then $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}$. This shows that any eigenvalue of an integer matrix is an algebraic integer.

To get the converse, you need only show that any such polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of some such matrix. Do you know how to show that part?

Comment: Ohh okay, now I can do it. Its just opposite thing of getting rational canonical form.